# Rails - How to use a method from a controller in application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple method in the `ApplicationController` that makes a call to database and load some data. I would need to run it in `application.rb`, like this:

```
MY_CONST = method_in_application_controller
```

But I get this error:

```
<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `method_in_application_controller' for main:Object (NameError)
```

How to load the data in from database in `application.rb` file?

Thank you.

Comment: edited answer to add a example of how to do this, rather than simply advising against it

Answer (score 3):

Really, you shouldn't. The better approach would be to refactor the controller method into somewhere globally accessible, such as a file in the `config/initializers` file or in application.rb itself. Then call it from the controller. The reason being that controller methods have access to special variables such as `request` and `params` which won't be available elsewhere. So it's one of those aspects of Rails development which can be considered part of the framework's design. It's easier to learn how to do things the right way.

---

This being said, it is possible.

Say I have a route in `PagesController` called `root`. It's easy to initialize the controller:

```
controller = PagesController.new
```

but running `controller.root` raises an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `parameters' for nil:NilClass
```

Some context is required to explain why this error was raised. My controller has a secure_params method which is called whenever any route is run. This methods expects a `params` object to be defined in the controller. I also have a `before_action` in my controller which references `session`. Both these objects are defined on the `request` object, which I can "mock" like so:

```
class FakeRequest
  def parameters
    {}
  end 
  def session
    {}
  end 
end
```

which can be used like this:

```
controller = PagesController.new
controller.request = FakeRequest.new
controller.root
```

This will run the controller action, however the fake request object may need to be altered depending on what your controllers require to function correctly.

If you're adamant about sharing controller methods throughout your app, it's probably easier to use class methods. This removes the necessity to construct a fake request and instantiate the controller.